# MacOS connected OpenVPN, but no internet access

Tags: openvpn, mac-osx

I already have an OpenVPN server. It worked correctly for Windows and Linux Client, but it did not work for MacOS. It can be connected but has no internet access.

Anyone, please help me to configure the problem or suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try the basic pings? pinging the server, pinging a other lan/vpn-target, pinging a public ip? Tried if the dns is working?

Comment: Yes, I got timeouted when using ping command

Comment: don't hide the results, show them ua please by editing the question